# Encrypted Text Returns Weird Characters When Decrypted Using DESCryptographer

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography

If I define encrypted text and decrypted text in the same brackets like,

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SymmetricCryptograperManager symmetricCryptograperManager = new SymmetricCryptograperManager();
        int key = 55999;
        var schema = symmetricCryptograperManager.GetSymmetricCryptographer(SymmetricCryptographyStrategy.DESCryptography, "000" + key.ToString());

        string textToBeEncrpted = "ozgur547@gmail.com";
        Console.WriteLine(textToBeEncrpted);

        string encryptedText = schema.Encrypt(textToBeEncrpted);
        Console.WriteLine(encryptedText);

        string decryptedText = schema.Decrypt(encryptedText);            
        Console.WriteLine(decryptedText);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Output is fine:

```
ozgur547@gmail.com
E+jPjrGaU9+IveRt/XdZzUHAerV8+VBG
ozgur547@gmail.com
```

But, at some point in my code, I have to define this `E+jPjrGaU9+IveRt/XdZzUHAerV8+VBG` encrypted text manually like,

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        SymmetricCryptograperManager symmetricCryptograperManager = new SymmetricCryptograperManager();
        int key = 55999;
        var schema = symmetricCryptograperManager.GetSymmetricCryptographer(SymmetricCryptographyStrategy.DESCryptography, "000" + key.ToString());

        //string textToBeEncrpted = "ozgur547@gmail.com";
        //Console.WriteLine(textToBeEncrpted);

        //string encryptedText = schema.Encrypt(textToBeEncrpted);
        //Console.WriteLine(encryptedText);

        string decryptedText = schema.Decrypt("E+jPjrGaU9+IveRt/XdZzUHAerV8+VBG");            
        Console.WriteLine(decryptedText);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Unfortunatelly I got back this `?6i?547@gmail.com`

Below is the clas where encrypt and decrypt comes from:

```
public class DESCryptographer : SymmetricCryptographer
{
    private readonly DESCryptoServiceProvider _des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
    public DESCryptographer(string key) : base(key)
    {

        _des.GenerateIV();
        IV = _des.IV;
    }

    public DESCryptographer(string key, string iV) : base(key, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(iV))
    {

    }

    public override string Encrypt(string plainText)
    {
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        ICryptoTransform cEncryptor = _des.CreateEncryptor(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Key), IV);
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream,
            cEncryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        writer.Write(plainText);
        writer.Flush();
        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        writer.Flush();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)memoryStream.Length);
    }

    public override string Decrypt(string encryptedText)
    {
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream
            (Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText));
        ICryptoTransform cDecryptor = _des.CreateDecryptor(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Key), IV);
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream,
            cDecryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(cryptoStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        return reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

And, this is the main class:

```
public abstract class SymmetricCryptographer
{
    public string Key { get; }
    public byte[] IV { get; protected set; }

    protected SymmetricCryptographer(string key)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(key), "Key should not be null");
        }

        this.Key = key;
    }

    protected SymmetricCryptographer(string key, byte[] iV)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(key), "Key should not be null");
        }

        this.Key = key;
        this.IV = iV ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(iV), "IV should not be null");
    }

    public abstract string Encrypt(string plainText);
    public abstract string Decrypt(string encryptedText);
}
```

How should I get a correct result when I put encrypted texts manually?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since it's only the first few characters being corrupted, it's clear that you're not getting the IV right. You need to make sure that the IV used during decryption is the same as that used in encryption. That usually means it needs to be *stored* alongside the ciphertext and explicitly supplied during decryption. I can't follow exactly what your code is doing with IVs but it's clear in your second example that *you're not supplying an IV at all*.

Comment: Also, it's 2018, not 1998. You really shouldn't be using DES.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thank you very much, you saved my day. Write it as answer so I can commend and make it an accepted answer